# Paho client for java generating folder like paho101658642587966-tcp1270011883. what is the importance of this?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, mqtt, paho

I am using Paho client for java to connect to activeMq over mqtt. I noticed one strange thing. There are several folder created having names like "paho101658642587966-tcp1270011883" and having empty .lck files. Why are these used and when are they created.

Answer (score 7):

These files are created to store inflight messages for QOS2 message before their delivery to the broker can be confirmed.

They are created by the [MQTTDefaultFilePersistence](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/persist/MqttDefaultFilePersistence.html) class, you can change the directory name and path by creating your own MQTTDefaultFilePresistence object and passing it to the [MQTTClient](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttClient.html) constructor.

You can also switch to a in memory store, but this will change how QOS2 messages are handled if the client crashes before a delivery can be confirmed.

Comment: I am not using QOS2 messages.

Comment: That doesn't matter, the storage is allocated incase you later do publish/subscribe at a higher QOS

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the /tmp directory for client execution as:

```
String receiverId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

IMqttClient receiver = new MqttClient(
                "tcp://" + properties.getProperty("host") + ":" + properties.getProperty("port"), receiverId, new MqttDefaultFilePersistence("/tmp"));
```